# doorstop: command not found (very simple installation instructions)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, git-bash

I would just like to test and try doorstop / see doorstop in action on my Ubuntu laptop.

In the instructions here https://pypi.org/project/doorstop/0.0.13/ it says that if I `pip3 install doorstop`, doorstop should then be available on the command line.
However, when I do this and then try to use doorstop on the command line I get `doorstop: command not found`. If I run Python3 and `import doorstop` (which seems to work), in Python3 I still haven't been able to use any of the commands on the doorstop website. I also haven't seen any information about this online.

Thanks,
Milan

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus have asked on there. It is coding rather than software rec so wasn't sure